# Table in react bootstrap. How can i make it fit inside a container?

Tags: css, reactjs, datatable

I am using react bootstrap table to show my data. The table is not responsive and has a over-proportioned size on the right side.

Look also at the picture showing that the table is much larger than the other components.

I have tried to include a few css elements such as container, width, max-width, among others however nothing worked.
I am importing the Bootstrap CSS using this: import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
Thanks in advance.

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import '../../../../src/styles.css'


export default function Datatable({ data }) {
    const columns = data[0] && Object.keys(data[0]);
    return (
   
        <table class="table" >                    
                <thead class=" table-striped table-bordered table-sm ">
                     <tr  >{data[0] && columns.map((heading) => <th>{heading}</th>)}</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class=" table-striped table-bordered table-sm " > 
                    {data.map((row) => (
                    <tr>
                    { columns.map((column) => (
                        <td>{row[column]}</td>
                    ))}
                    </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
          
        </table>
     
    );
}
```

styles.css

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
}
table  {
  background: #f89c9c;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}


thead {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Base.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from "./Menu"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/row";


const Base = ({
    title = "My Title",
    description = "My description",
    className = "",
    children 
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Menu />   
            <Container fluid className="bg-light" >
                    
                    <Container fluid >
                    <div className="col bg-light text-dark text-left pt-5" >
                        <Row >
                        <h2 className="col-9 display-4 ml-0 font-weight-bold">{title}</h2>
                   
                        <Button  variant="link"  className=" btn bg-light text-dark font-weight-bold">Investor</Button>
                        <Button  variant="link" className="btn bg-light text-dark font-weight-bold">Borrower</Button>
                        <Button  variant="link" className=" btn bg-light text-dark font-weight-bold">Charity</Button>
                        </Row>
                        <p className=" lead ml-0 font-weight-bold">{description}</p>
                    </div>
                    </Container>
           
                <div className={className}>{children}</div>
           
            </Container >


            <footer className="footer bg-dark mt-auto py-3">
```

UserDashboard.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Base from '../core/Base'

import './helper/EnhancedTable';
import { Dash } from './helper/EnhancedTable'

const UserDashboard = () => {
    return (

        <Base title="User dashboard">   
               
                <Dash ></Dash>
               
        </Base>

    )
}
export default UserDashboard;
```

Table.js

```
import {API} from "../../backend"
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Datatable from './datatable';

require("es6-promise").polyfill();
require("isomorphic-fetch");


export default function Dash() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  //now we create the quesry state
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");

  const [searchColumns, setSearchColumns] = useState(["description", "borrower_name"]);

  //this is the function that we want tpo fire when the dependencies are triggered
  useEffect(() => {

    //fetch will make the call to the server
    fetch(`${API}project/`, {method: "GET"})

    //then response will handle answer from server transforming the HTTP data into JSON data
    .then((response) => response.json())

    //now that we access to the JSON data from server we will get if from the local storage
    .then((json) => setData(json))
  }, []);

  function search(rows) {
    
    return rows.filter(
      (row ) =>
        searchColumns.some(column => row[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
        )
      ); 
  }

  const columns = data[0] && Object.keys(data[0])
  return (
   
   
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={q} onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value) }/>
          {
            columns && columns.map(column =>
             <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={searchColumns.includes(column)} 
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const checked = searchColumns.includes(column);
                    setSearchColumns((prev) => checked
                      ? prev.filter((sc) => sc !== column)
                      : [...prev, column]
                      );
                  }} 
                />
                {column}
            </label>)
          }

             <Datatable data={search(data)} />
       
        </div>

  )
 
}
export {Dash};
```

[image]

Comment: Declare a <div className="table-responsive"></div> outside the table. If you are using a bootstrap with react then you can use bootstrap .table-responsive class. it make you data table responsive.

Comment: Welcome, I hope it's working for you and solved your problem.